# How do I make a deb in windows?

Tags: windows, deb

I need too install a broadcom sta wireless driver and since the internet doesn't work without it I figured I'll have to make a deb.

How can I make a .deb in windows precisely?

Comment: Can I ask why you would need to do that?  You can install broadcom drivers offline as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: You can do that but it is really dangerous and pointless according to some users here

Answer (score 1):

It is not advised to do this as many things can go wrong, as [fossfredom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) said it's much better installing broadcom via [offline method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx).

Although if you really need there are two ways, the reliable one, although it spends more time, and the fast one, although not the most reliable:

### Use a Virtual Machine

*Reliable method*

Install Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine, if don't know how to do it, see [This Guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox).

Then just create your .deb, if don't know how to do it, see [This Guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html).

### Use PyPackager

*Fast method*

[Download PyPackager](https://github.com/khertan/PyPackager) and then create the .deb file using it, if in doubt see [This Page](http://wiki.maemo.org/PyPackager).

---

See that if you are not familiar to creating .deb files it will be very complicated, difficult and frustrating accomplishing what you want to.

If you don't feel very confident about creating .deb files you shouldn't opt for the Fast method.

In addition I guess that if you try to install your drivers in a LiveUSB (it can´t be a CD/DVD, and the LiveUSB needs to be created with some space to store changes made) and then install Ubuntu through the LiveUSB you will have your drivers installed easily, but it´s just a shot, not sure if it would work.